# determine if geography point falls on geography polygon line

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, sql-server-2014

I understand that you cannot check if a geography point touches for example a geography polygon (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2008/10/24/sql-20008-spatial-samples-part-n-of-n-conditional-methods.aspx)) using something like this, which is possible in the geometry world:

```
WHERE A.Geo.STTouches(@s0) = 1
```

Is there a way to achieve this in the geography world? I guess a solution would be to transform the geography polygon + geography point into their geometry equivalents?

PS:

This should also work with complex polygons - such as this one with holes:

POLYGON ((99.999999999999986 5.3926387744713564E-14, 101.00000000000001 5.3926387744713564E-14, 100.99999999999987 1.0000000000000155, 100.00000000000013 1.0000000000000155, 99.999999999999986 5.3926387744713564E-14), (100.20000000000003 0.19999999999992918, 100.19999999999989 0.79999999999990257, 100.80000000000011 0.79999999999990234, 100.79999999999998 0.19999999999992912, 100.20000000000003 0.19999999999992918))

[image]

Comment: What about using `STIntersects()` instead of `STTouches()`?

Comment: I want to know that it lies exactly on the border. STIntersects() would not tell me this. hope this makes sense?

Comment: Ah… that is a horse of a different color. Basically, you want to know if the point intersects with the *boundary* of the polygon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that my statement of your wanting to track whether or not the given point intersects with the boundary of your polygon. The below should do the trick:

```
SELECT @point.STIntersects(@polygon.RingN(1));
```

In essence, you're getting the outer boundary with `RingN(1)` (I'm making an assumption that this is a simple polygon, so the first ring should be the outer boundary) and then checking whether *that* intersects with the point you care about.

Edit: If you want to check if a given point lies on the boundary of *any* ring in the given polygon, something like this should do the trick:

```
select n.n as [IntersectedRingNumber], 
   @polygon.RingN(n) as [IntersectedRing]
from dbo.Numbers as n
where n <= @polygon.NumRings()
   and @point.STIntersects(@polygon.RingN(n)) = 1;
```

Comment: That's a great idea. Ideally, it should work with complex polygons as well - see PS in original question.

Comment: Absolutely the way to do it.  Depending on the level of accuracy you are looking for, you **may** want to consider a small buffer to cater for potential coordinate rounding issues and/or data quality.  For example `SELECT @point.STBuffer(0.1)...`.  This circa. 10cm buffer would be accurate enough for most geography requirements but allow 10.9999999999993 to equal 11 (or 10.99999).

Comment: @csetzkorn: Yes it should. AFAIK, ring 1 is always the outermost ring and therefore will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks but how can I check whether point lies on any inner holes borders with a little buffer?

Comment: @JonBellamy: I thought about your comment on my drive in today and that's a really good point. The order of operations matters, of course; a buffer around the outer ring results in a narrow two-dimensional band while a ring around the buffer is still just a one-dimensional line. I know you know this, but I'm stating it for explicitness' sake.

Comment: Thanks this is great stuff. Just curious, looking at the original simple scenario would this: SELECT @point.STBuffer(0.1).STIntersects(@polygon.RingN(1)); cater for precision issues?

Comment: It should. What you're trying to avoid is having to match two one-dimensional objects. Making either of them "fuzzy" by adding a buffer should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @BenThul You are absolutely right, the buffer should be applied directly to a Spatial instance which will not then have it's ring plucked out (which results in a LINESTRING and puts you back to where you started).  The way that csetzkorn has suggested the implementation in his last comment is the correct order of things.

Comment: @JonBellamy: We're all in agreement; I'm just documenting it for those that stumble on this in the future.